# Detecting running Equinox IApplication ID

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox, efxclipse

I have RCP E4 Application with GUI (JavaFX). It also contains several IApplication instances without GUI. The problem that, there are some DS services that run automatically, I want to detect which application (IApplication/product ID) started from within those DS services. Is that possible and what information I can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IApplicationContext` contains a number of methods to tell you about what it calls the 'Branding App'.

`getBrandingApplication` gives you the id of the running application (always org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application` for e4 for example).

`getBrandingId` is the product id.

`getBrandingName` is the name specified for the product.

In an e4 app you can just inject `IApplicationContext`. `IApplication` apps are given the cpntext as a parameter to the start method. It can also be found by searching the OSGi services:

```java
IApplicationContext getApplicationContext(BundleContext context) {
    Collection<ServiceReference<IApplicationContext>> references;
    try {
        references = context.getServiceReferences(IApplicationContext.class, "(eclipse.application.type=main.thread)"); 
    } catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
        return null;
    }
    if (references == null || references.isEmpty())
        return null;
    // assumes the application context is available as a service
    ServiceReference<IApplicationContext> firstRef = references.iterator().next();
    IApplicationContext result = context.getService(firstRef);
    if (result != null) {
        context.ungetService(firstRef);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

(above code adapted from `org.eclipse.core.internal.runtimeInternalPlatform`)

Comment: It gives me product id and name, but when IApplication executed getBrandingId() returns null

Comment: If it is started by specifying `-application xx' it isn't part of a product so there is no product id.